# Changing property of tags using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the property of tags using JS ? I've tried these codes, but it doesn't work for radio buttons though.

**JS Code**

```
obj = document.getElementById("personne").style;
if (str[0] == 'c')
    obj.disabled = false;
```

**HTML code**

```
<input id="personne" type="radio" name="choice" value="personne" disabled />
```

Here I'm trying to change the **disabled** property of a radio button to become **enabled**.
Any help please ?

Comment: disabled is not a style, it's an attribute.

Comment: `document.getElementById("personne").disabled = false`. As already said, `disabled` is an attribute/property of the *element*, it's not a style.

Comment: Perhaps change `obj=document.getElementById("personne").style;` to `obj=document.getElementById("personne");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (str[0] === "c") {
    document.getElementById("personne").disabled = false;
}
```

`disabled` is an *attribute* of the `input` element, **not** a style, so accessing the `style` property of the element is incorrect.

I've used [strict equality comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) (which are best practice for JavaScript), and I've removed the global that you've leaked inadvertently from **not** [declaring your variables with `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
> var obj=document.getElementById("personne");
>     if(str[0]=='c')
>        obj.disabled=false;
```

You were trying to use `disabled` as a **style** attribute which it is not . Its a **property attribute** of the input element that is a **boolean attribute** which means if you it is present in the element when it is declared it will have the desired effect or else it will be treated *as if* you specified a `false` value for it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?